# what is the ideal way to set foreign key in ecommerce database

Tags: sql, laravel, database-design, schema, e-commerce

For the time I am making a database schema for a small ecommerce site.
There are two tables product (main) and category. I want to define relation between them using foreign key, but I have a doubt that in which table should I define column which contain primary key of anothor table.
Currently I am working in laravel and I want that whenever I use product table so that category name also can be use there.

table: column

**product**: id, prd_name, prd_price, prd_desc...

**category**: cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc...

Where should I add column for foreign key, please help me out and guide me the ideal way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does you product belongs to single category or multiple categories?

Comment: product belongs to single category

Comment: So you can set `cat_id` in product table and use [hasMany()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation in category model and use [belongsTo()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) in your product model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put cat_id column as a foreign key in table **product** referencing cat_id column in **category** table.